# Second radio button only fire once when in update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two radio button in an udpate panel. The first radio button does not have postback while other one has. The first time the page loads the first radio button is selected and when selecting the second radio button the checkchanged event fires. But when i go back to the first radio button and then select second radio button the checkchanged event does not fires. Any suggestions?? Code goes below

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Update" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdo1" runat="server" class="bodycontent" GroupName="status" Checked="true" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="rdo2" runat="server" class="bodycontent" GroupName="status"
                    OnCheckedChanged="rdo2_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="chk1_CheckedChanged" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rdo2" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chk1" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: check for javascript errors on your browser console.

Comment: There is no javascript errors as this is only code i was trying to make it work.